# C# using DirectoryEntry.Properties["mail"] vs. UserPrincipal.EmailAddress

Tags: c#, active-directory

We have a C# program that gets a list of AD users in our Domain Users group. We noticed that doing the following returned a null email address for some users that definitely had the email address field in AD.

```
UserPrincipal up = (UserPrincipal)principal;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.EmailAddress))
{
     string userid = up.UserPrincipalName.ToLower().Replace("@example.com", "");
     users.Add(new ADUser {
         UserName = userid,
         Name = $"{userid} ({CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(up.DisplayName.ToLower())})",
         EmailAddress = up.EmailAddress.ToLower()
     });
}
```

However, doing this returned the missing users.

```
UserPrincipal up = (UserPrincipal)principal;
DirectoryEntry de = up.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

if (de.Properties["mail"].Value != null)
{
    string userid = up.UserPrincipalName.ToLower().Replace("@example.com", "");
    users.Add(new ADUser
    {
        UserName = userid,
        Name = $"{userid} ({CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(up.DisplayName.ToLower())})",
        EmailAddress = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString()
    });
}
```

What is the difference between `DirectoryEntry.Properties["mail"]` and `UserPrincipal.EmailAddress` fields? Are two different values pulled from AD, and if so, is there an easy way to compare what the values are (such as a script)?

Comment: Is this random or rather, it always returns null for specific users?

Comment: Always returns null for specific users.

Comment: Checked our code that is in production for like 10 years, different searchers use either first or second way of accessing the data (from the `UserPrincipal` or from the `DirectoryEntry` below it) and it always work correctly in both cases. What AD you use?